# CUDA stuck building in x86 using CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, cmake, 64-bit

(Windows 10, Cuda 8.0, VS 2015, CMake 3.7.0

I am having trouble building a library with a CUDA kernel.

My project has a top level CMakeLists.txt which includes a sub-CMakeLists.txt.

At the top level:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project (robot)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
#...some more stuff
include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/projects/subproject/CMakeLists.txt)
```

Then, in the subproject CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SUBPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/projects/subproject)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SUBPROJECT_HEADER ${SUBPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SUBPROJECT_SOURCE ${SUBPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SUBPROJECT_CUDA ${SUBPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cu)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SUBPROJECT_CUDA_HEADER ${SUBPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cuh)

cuda_add_library(subproject STATIC ${SUBPROJECT_HEADER} ${SUBPROJECT_SOURCE} ${SUBPROJECT_CUDA_HEADER} ${SUBPROJECT_CUDA})
target_include_directories(subproject PRIVATE ${SUBPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
#some other includes and target_includes here...

target_link_libraries(subproject <some links here>)
```

In my source directory, I have a .cuh and a .cu file.  These are based off the simple VectorAdd test:

kernel.cuh:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

__global__ void VectorAdd(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n);
int test();
```

And kernel.cu:

```
#include "kernel.cuh"

#define SIZE 1024



__global__ void VectorAdd(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n) {
    int i = threadIdx.x;

    if (i < n){
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}

int test() {

    int *a, *b, *c;
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;

    a = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    b = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    c = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc(&d_a, SIZE * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&d_b, SIZE * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&d_c, SIZE * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i;
        c[i] = 0;

    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_c, c, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    VectorAdd<<< 1, SIZE >>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, SIZE);

    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("c[%d] = %d\n", i, c[i]);
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);

    return 0;

}
```

I include Kernel.cuh in a different C++ file in my project.  Trying to compile my solution, I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1112 module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'  subproject  C:\path_to_proj\build\CMakeFiles\subproject.dir\projects\subproject\src\Release\subproject_generated_kernel.cu.obj  1
```

which then leads to the fact that the .lib cannot be found.  What is the cause of this error?  Is there something I need to add in the CMakeLists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this is the correct solution to your problem. But it works for me and I work with nearly the same configuration as you (windows 10, visual studio 13, cuda 8.0, cmake 3.7).

In my cmake file I have in addition to your `find cuda` command the following code. Maybe the first line fits to your error massage)

```
set(CUDA_64_BIT_DEVICE_CODE ON CACHE STRING "Compile device code in 64 bit mode" FORCE)
```

and to complete my cuda-cmake list (the last line could also help, it force the linker to find the x64 cuda lib):

```
find_path(CUDA_CUT_INCLUDE_DIR
      helper_cuda.h
      PATHS "$ENV{NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT}" "$ENV{NVSDKCUDA_ROOT}" "$ENV{NVCUDASAMPLES_ROOT}"
      PATH_SUFFIXES "common/inc" "CUDA Samples/v7.5/common/inc" "v7.5/common/inc"
      DOC "Location of helper_cuda.h"
      NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CUDA_CUT_INCLUDE_DIR})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}/../lib/x64)
```

I hope some of this can help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That fixed part of the bug...I have a new bug, not sure if it's related, that my program now can't find certain .dll's.  It seems that the second part tries to fix that - but when the second part is added, suddenly it's looking for certain lib files I've never had to copy over.  Why is this?

Also, the last line has an unmatched paren :)

Comment: (Just to help provide more information, the error if I add your lines is now "Cannot open file glut32.lib," wondering if you've ever seen anything like this?

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helps you. My second path is just to add the include paths to the visual studio project. And the last line shows VS where to find the cuda.lib file. glut32 is a library from OpenGL. It is maybe another question and has nothing to do with cuda (you can use cuda without glut), But for you interest, you have to specify the link directories to glut, (e.g.: link_directories(/path/to/glut) ). And you need to copy the relevant dlls to your binary path.

Comment: I am not finding that last part necessary.  *shrug*

Comment: I would like to help you, but I need more informations about your cmake-file. Maybe you can open a new question. I think the parts of you file   `some other includes and target_includes here...` and `target_link_libraries(subproject <some links here>` are relevant. And the error massages you get.